# Correct Modal for Specific ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 application using Bootstrap 4. I have a list of items being displayed from a database using a `@foreach` loop. Each item has a "Status Code" link.

I'm wanting the user to be able to click on that link and for a modal to pop up for the respective item. With my current code, I believe the modal for the first items always shows no matter which link I click on.

What do I need to do so that when I click on say the 5th item, the modal for the 5th item appears as opposed to the same modal appearing for each item?

Here's what I have so far:

**View**

```
<div class="row">
@foreach(var Submission in Model.Submissions)
{
    < div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card text-center my-3 shadow">
            ...
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <b>Status: </b><a data-target="#StatusCodeUpdate" asp-route-id="@Submission.ID" data-toggle="modal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Submission.Status)</a>

                < !--Modal-- >
                <div class="modal fade" id="StatusCodeUpdate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StatusCodeUpdateLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="StatusCodeUpdateLabel">Update Status Code</h5>
                        <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        ...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

**Controller/Code Behind**

```
public class TeamleadModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    private readonly SubmissionContext _context;

    public TeamleadModel(SubmissionContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Submissions = await _context.Submissions.ToListAsync();


    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class Submission
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string Goal { get; set; }
    [Column("Timeline")]
    public string DesiredCompletionDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Files { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
}
```

Comment: please retype the question.and also state your problem more clearly

Comment: @JephrenNaicker better?

Comment: you could have an onclick listener on your status button that fires an ajax request to the server. the server would return the contents of your modal body. In the success function of the ajax call, set contents of modal-body to the data returned by the server.

Comment: @GregH I'm hesitant to do that sense all of the information is already on the page. Is it good practice to make multiple calls to eat the server for the same info? Thoughts?

Comment: no definitely not, a complete reproduceable example that includes the controller code,model and full modal would go a long way. If I'm now understanding where you're currently at correctly, you could put a data attribute or data attributes on the `<a>` tag that triggers the modal to show then on click of the a tag, dynamically set whatever you need to in the modal based on the data attributes in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @GregH I added the `Model` and `Controller` to my question. I hope it helps. And yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The `<a>` tag already brings up the modal. I just need it to have the correct modal show which would be the one that corresponds to the ID of the one I clicked. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: please add the markup for the modal body as well so we can tell what exactly you're trying to populate

Comment: @GregH That maybe complicating my question. I believe I can figure out how to get the modal to fill with the appropriate information. I just need to make sure the correct modal shows up. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand now- please see my answer. Note some may consider it bad practice to render a bunch of different modals on the page when they really represent the same data. This can be done by only rendering one modal and dynamically populating it's contents on click. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `data-target` to the appropriate modal. See below:

```
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
       <b>Status: </b><a data-target="#modal-@Submission.ID" asp-route-id="@Submission.ID" data-toggle="modal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Submission.Status)</a>

       <div id="modal-@Submission.ID" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StatusCodeUpdateLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="StatusCodeUpdateLabel">Update Status Code</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                              <label>Submission first name: </label><span id="modal-firstname">@Submission.FirstName</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            ...
                        </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Currently you are rendering multiple modals with the same id so the `data-target` is using the first modal to select to show. In html, `id`s should always be unique. You can use the `Submission.Id` to make each modal's id unique and to set the appropriate `data-target` on your `<a>` tag which is used to trigger the modal.